# ¿Por qué me da error Can't determine Firebase Database URL. Be sure to include databaseURL option when calling firebase.initializeApp()

Tags: firebase, realtime-database

Tengo este código index.html y me da error: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.  Be sure to include databaseURL option when calling firebase.initializeApp(). ¿Cuál pudiera ser la causa?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="">
        <div>
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" id="nombre">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="mensaje">Mensaje</label>
            <textarea id="mensaje"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
    </form>

    <ul id="chatUl">
        <li>
            <b>Nombre: </b>Mensaje
        </li>
        <li>
            <b>Nombre: </b>Mensaje
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.7/firebase.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->

    <script>
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "{aquí coloqué el apikey}",
            authDomain: "chatpersp.firebaseapp.com",
            projectId: "chatpersp",
            storageBucket: "chatpersp.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "1053091078026",
            appId: "1:1053091078026:web:5818e63c543702a8893273"
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
       

        var txtNombre = document.getElementById('nombre')
        var txtMensaje = document.getElementById('mensaje')
        var btnEnviar = document.getElementById('btnEnviar')
        var chatUl = document.getElementById('chatUl')

        btnEnviar.addEventListener("click", function () {
            var nombre = txtNombre.value;
            var mensaje = txtMensaje.value;
            var html = "<li><b>" + nombre + ": </b>" + mensaje + "</li>";
            chatUl.innerHTML += html;

            firebase.database().ref('chat').push({
                name: nombre,
                message: mensaje
            })

        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de

```
var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "{aquí coloqué el apikey}",
            authDomain: "chatpersp.firebaseapp.com",
            projectId: "chatpersp",
            storageBucket: "chatpersp.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "1053091078026",
            appId: "1:1053091078026:web:5818e63c543702a8893273"
        };
```

tienes que agregar la url

```
var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "{aquí coloqué el apikey}",
            authDomain: "chatpersp.firebaseapp.com",
            projectId: "chatpersp",
            databaseURL: "https://blabla.firebaseio.com",
            torageBucket: "chatpersp.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "1053091078026",
            appId: "1:1053091078026:web:5818e63c543702a8893273"
        };
```